# Unable to Locate Downloaded File on Android from Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage

I am downloading a file from firebase storage. When the file is downloaded it appears in alerting notifications on the phone but If I try to locate it in the File Manager it is no where to be found.

```
public void giveDownload(Context context, String fileName, String destinationDirectory, String url) {
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationDirectory, fileName);
    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}
```

I am calling this as :

```
giveDownload(DownloadMethod.this, "TestingFile", DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, testing.getFilename());
```

I know I am missing something but I am not sure where. I have tried all the solutions I could find. Please help.

Comment: `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir()` The file goes to an app specific directory. See getExternalFilesDir().The MediaStore does not scan such directories hence Gallery apps do not see them. But a file manager can if not on an Android 11 device. Look in the ../Android/data/ folder for your app.

Comment: There is nothing in the /Android/data/ folder when I open it on my phone, but I can see files if I open it on the computer. I want to have a folder created like what happens with Whatsapp. A folder is created and your data is stored in that in the phone storage.

Comment: I have no idea what kind of folder whatsapp would have or where it would be located. Strange you did not tell full path.

Comment: `testing.getFilename()` Does that deliver a https url? Quite confusing.